# How to ease highlight animation in iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, animation, ios-charts

When highlighting a section of a PieChartView (from [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)), the highlighted selection jumps out without animation by default. Is there a way to ease animation between the standard and highlighted effect?

Standard appearance:

[image: Standard Pie Chart]

Highlighted appearance

[image: Highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

The size of the selected segment is controlled by the `selectionShift` property of the dataSet. A value of `0` means that there will be no change to the element when it's selected.

It's possible to change this value over time, controlled by the built in animator function.

To trigger the animator when you select a segment of the pie chart, implement the `chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)` function of the chart view delegate.

Example:

```
override func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {

    let animator = Animator()

    animator.updateBlock = {
        // Usually the phase is a value between 0.0 and 1.0
        // Multiply it so you get the final phaseShift you want
        let phaseShift = 10 * animator.phaseX

        let dataSet = chartView.data?.dataSets.first as? PieChartDataSet
        // Set the selectionShift property to actually change the selection over time
        dataSet?.selectionShift = CGFloat(phaseShift)

        // In order to see the animation, trigger a redraw every time the selectionShift property was changed
        chartView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    // Start the animation by triggering the animate function with any timing function you like
    animator.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.3, easingOption: ChartEasingOption.easeInCubic)
}
```